# Re-using an already created object from another file in Python

Tags: python, class, object

Say I have 3 '.py files named file1.py, file2.py and report.py and each have different classes in them.
In file1.py I have created an object named report_write in  classA that refers to class Report in report.py
Is it possible for me to re-use this same object report_write in classB in  file2.py that refers to the same class Report in report.py ?

Example-

```
# =============================================================================
# report.py
# =============================================================================
class Report():
#Generates Report Output Screen/File with selectable destiantions and verb. level
   def __init__(self):  
       
       self.reportFile = open(*filepath*,'w')
       
   
    def write_text(self, text):
        
        self.reportFile.write(text) 
        

# =============================================================================
# file1.py
# =============================================================================
class classA():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.report_write = Report()
        
        
    def GUI_Display(self): 
        self.report_write.write_text("Something")
        
        
# =============================================================================
# file2.py
# =============================================================================

class classB():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.report_write = Report()
        
        
    def next_GUI_Display(self): 
        self.report_write.write_text("Something Else")
```

Comment: If `2.py` imports the variable from `1.py`, it can use the object.

Comment: @Barmar any idea how I can do that ? I'm relatively new to this?.
Just to be clear, the object obj1 is being created within  classA in 1.py and classB in 2.py

Comment: You don't use objects from other files, you use global variables and functions by importing.

Comment: Please show example code, and how you're trying to use the object.

Comment: @Barmar Ive added an example code, hope it helps

Comment: I don't see the problem. Put `from 1 import Report` in both `2.py` and `3.py`. As @MisterMiyagi points out, you need to rename `1.py` to a valid module name (suggestion: `report.py`).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have edited the question and code now, hope everything is as should be

Comment: @Barmar the issue is that the text ``` Something Else``` from  file2.py does not get printed into the same text/report file that i have created in the report.py

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor so you can pass the same `Report` object to `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

classA.py

```
from report import Report

class classA():
    
    def __init__(self, report_write = None):
        self.report_write = report_write or Report()
        
        
    def GUI_Display(self): 
        self.report_write.write_text("Something")
```

classB.py

```
from report import Report

class classB():
    
    def __init__(self, report_write = None):
        self.report_write = report_write or Report()
        
        
    def next_GUI_Display(self): 
        self.report_write.write_text("Something Else")
```

Then the caller would be like this:

```
from report import Report
from classA import ClassA
from classB immport ClassB

my_report = Report()
obj_a = ClassA(my_report)
obj_b = ClassB(my_report)
```